# Unity playing animation a chosen amount of times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I tried playing my animation a amount of times by script, but the only thing happening is it running stuck and needed to be closed by taskmanager. My code:

```
    int NeededAni;
    public Animator Sheep;


    void Start()
    {
        PickRandomNumber(9);

        StartCoroutine(PlaySheepInterval(NeededAni, 0F));
    }

    private IEnumerator PlaySheepInterval (int n, float Time)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            Sheep.SetFloat("SceneLoaded", 1f);
            --n;
            Debug.Log(n);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time);
        }

        while (n <= 0)
        {
            Sheep.SetFloat("SceneLoaded", 0f);
        }
    }

    public void PickRandomNumber(int maxInt)
    {
        NeededAni = Random.Range(1, maxInt + 1);
        Debug.Log(NeededAni);
    }
```

How can you solve this?
PS: Sceneloaded is the parameter attached to the animator.
PS: The float "waitForSeconds" was necessary but I dont really use it.

Comment: I guess your code gets stuck in `while (n <= 0)` since `n` should have value `0` but is not further modified.

Comment: That aint the case right? the integer n gets the value picked by PickRandomNumber(9) so the n value at the start should be between 1-9. Which is the case cause I see that in the console

Comment: you are decrementing the value of `n` in the previous `while (n > 0)` loop by doing `--n;`, so `n` should exit this loop with a value of `0`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a solution.

```
    void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(PlaySheepInterval(NeededAni, 3.2F));

    }

    private IEnumerator PlaySheepInterval(int n, float time)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            Sheep.SetFloat("SceneLoaded", 1f);
            n = n - 1;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
            Debug.Log(n);
        }

       if (n <= 0)
        {
            Sheep.SetFloat("SceneLoaded", 0f);
        }
    }
```

The 3.2F is the duration of the animation, so every 3.2 frames the n value gets reduced by 1 when there also is a animation complete.
[Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1039489/play-animation-a-specific-number-of-times.html)